# Puphpet + Vagrant + AWS returning either default Puphpet page or Index Of page

Tags: amazon-ec2, vagrant, vagrantfile, puphpet, vagrant-aws

[index of page that I get back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkLg6.png)

For whatever reason whenever I launch an ec2 instance using vagrant and puphpet I get back the default puphpet page on my ec2 instance and if I modify my host file to use the public dns then I get back what looks like a directory if all of my project files. I'm also linking my github issue that I created so that you can see my config file. Also the hostname [www.bxs.test](http://www.bxs.test) does not render as well.
What is my /etc/host file supposed to look like? How do I get my website [www.bxs.test](http://www.bxs.test) to display my site?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a few issues here to address here

1. the default page you have meant one of the following issues

- your application is installed in the wrong location
- the address you're requesting not configured on the webserver and its showing default apache directory